# Facing problem for a Group by multiselect picklist

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I have a multiselect picklist called `status` with 3 values and 5 amount fields..The problem that i am facing is that whatever value i  select from `status`,My code is grouping by for all 3 values.

For e.g Assume that the values in `status` are A,B and C.

If i select A- All A,B and C values are getting aggregated.I want to group by only for the `Status` values that i select.

Below is the code that i have written

```
 if(isMezzRecordType == true)
{

     String groupDealStatus = 'SELECT Status__c,SUM(Equity_amount__c) equitySum,SUM(Equity_Payment_Amount__c) equityPayment,SUM(Debt_Payment_Amount__c) debtAmount,SUM(Debt_Amount__c) Debt,SUM(Japan_Debt_Amount__c) JapanDebtAmount From Log__c ';
     groupDealStatus+= whereClause;
     groupDealStatus+= 'GROUP BY Status__c ';

     AggregateResult[] totalDealResults= Database.query(groupDealStatus);

     for (AggregateResult tempTotal : totalDealResults) 
    {
    totalEquityAmt =calculateAmountString(Double.valueOF(tempTotal.get('equitySum')));

    equityPaymentAmt = calculateAmountString(Double.valueOF(tempTotal.get('equityPayment')));

    debtPaymentAmount = calculateAmountString(Double.valueOF(tempTotal.get('debtAmount')));

    debtAmount=calculateAmountString(Double.valueOF(tempTotal.get('Debt')));
   japanDebtMetAmount=calculateAmountString(Double.valueOF(tempTotal.get('JapanDebtAmount')));

   }  
}
```

In where clause status field has condition like below

```
         if(status!= null)
        {
            System.debug('status check*****'+status);
            temps = status.split(',',-1); 
            //whereClause+= ' '+'and'+'('+'Status__c in:temps';
             whereClause+= ' and (Status__c in:temps';

            if(isMezzRecordType && status!='Closed')
            {
              System.debug('*****inside status********');
              whereClause+=' '+'OR (Status__c=:statusCriteria AND Funding_Date__c=LAST_WEEK) OR (Debt_Payment_Date__c=LAST_WEEK) OR (Equity_Payment_Date__c=LAST_WEEK))';
         //   whereClause+=' '+'OR (Status__c=:statusCriteria OR Funding_Date__c=LAST_WEEK OR Debt_Payment_Date__c=LAST_WEEK))';

            }
            else
            {
              whereClause+=')';

            }
        }
```

Please help

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you populating that variable "whereClause"? It should contain something like " where Status__c in ('A') " built from the choices that you have made about which Status values to include.

Comment: @Doug i have updated the wherclause condition in my question..please check it

Comment: You could try doing system.debug on the whereClause once you have populated it. I see that you have an OR which means that you could be coming out with " where Status__c in ('A') or (Status__c=:statusCriteria AND Funding_Date__c=LAST_WEEK) " this OR part means that you could be retrieving rows which don't match the first part, i.e. have Status not A. These will then be aggregated by your group by.

Comment: @Doug i have to give this criteria as per the requirement....because whatever i select in the multiselect.... its mandatory to get the status__c=:statusCriteria,here statusCriteria have one specific value ''Closed" from the multi select picklist.

Comment: @Doug You are right if i remove that condition its aggregating whatever i select,but i want this condition too....is there any other way so that the requirements dont get clashed...please guide me...

Comment: The requirement is status has 3 fields closed,dead,Review. If the user selects any of the field other than closed the records should be displayed with the following condition.1) The status closed along with funding date entered within last week should be displayed. 2)The status closed along with Debt_Payment_Date__c or Equity_Payment_Date__c=LAST_WEEK entered within last week should be displayed.For these conditions i have written  whereClause+=' '+'OR (Status__c=:statusCriteria AND Funding_Date__c=LAST_WEEK) OR (Debt_Payment_Date__c=LAST_WEEK) OR (Equity_Payment_Date__c=LAST_WEEK))';

Comment: In that example it looks like some of the OR conditions do not refer to the status, so they will bring back all status. E.g. OR (Debt_Payment_Date__c=LAST_WEEK) will bring back rows of every status. The problem isn't with your code, it's with the formulation of your SOQL. Try experimenting in Developer Console until you get a query which meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Just a mistake in query.Just added brackets and it worked

```
whereClause+= ' and (Status__c in:temps';

if(isMezzRecordType && status!='Closed')
{
          System.debug('*****inside status********');
whereClause+=' '+'OR (Status__c=:statusCriteria AND (Funding_Date__c=LAST_WEEK OR Debt_Payment_Date__c=LAST_WEEK OR Equity_Payment_Date__c=LAST_WEEK)));

}
```

Thanks for the help @Doug :)